# USB hub + android device

Tags: android, usb, host, accessory

developers!

I have to connect active (powered from the outlet) hub to android device that supports otg. Actually there will be not one hub, but the cascade of 5 hubs connected one by another. So there will be several usb busses.

I'd like to ask if it's possible to monitor the bus in the USB accessory mode? This is preferred because I suspect the device will not charge in the usb host mode.
I've read documentation from here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html
It tells that usb host mode is used when I need to enumerate devices. 
But I can communicate with another accessories. Then I have to know their descriptors hence I have to know that accessory was attached. But I'm not sure how to construct this in context of active usb hub.

Could anyone please help with that?

Regards, Vladimir.